# Why would I pick BerkeleyDB JE v6 over v5?

Tags: java, berkeley-db-je

The [Oracle BDB release notes](http://www.oracle.com//technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/downloads/changelog-last-release-2340861.html) have no meat at all, unfortunately.

Why would I want to switch from BDB JE version 5 to version 6? Does it have significant performance improvements? Because if not, I can only see these two cons:

- v5 uses Sleepycat, v6 uses AGPL 3. Thus v5 is compatible with GPL v2+, whereas v6 requires me to go to GPL v3
- v5 works with Java 6, v6 requires Java 7